# How to get column names of a pandas.DataFrame from below given description of the data

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas

**Every column name ends with a colon and the next column name starts on newline with the previous line ended with a fullstop , so there should be a way to get a  list of column name from the string**

```
data_description = '''age: continuous.
workclass: Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Self-emp-inc, Federal-gov.
fnlwgt: continuous.
education: Bachelors, Some-college, 11th, HS-grad, Prof-school.
education-num: continuous.'''
```

**How can I get the below output**

```
Columns = ['age','workclass','fnlwgt','education','education-num']
```

Answer (score 2):

The title of your post says, **get column names of a pandas.DataFrame from below** and I don't see `pandas` code written anywhere in your explanation.

You could do this very easily through `pandas`:

First create your `dictionary` like this:

```
data_description = {'age': ['continuous.'],
'workclass': ['Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Self-emp-inc, Federal-gov.'],
'fnlwgt': ['continuous.'],
'education':[ 'Bachelors, Some-college, 11th, HS-grad, Prof-school.'],
'education-num': ['continuous.']}
```

Then create a `dataframe` using above `dict`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_description)
```

Then just say, `list(df.columns)` and it will give you all column names in a list.

```
In [1009]: list(df.columns)
Out[1009]: ['age', 'education', 'education-num', 'fnlwgt', 'workclass']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> Columns = [i.split(':')[0] for i in data_description.split() if ':' in i]
>>> Columns
['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num']
```

Comment: Thanks,  its working.   But I am not able to understand the code. what is this part of the code doing `for i in data_description.split()` ?

Comment: `data_description.split()` splits the `data_description` string on whitespace (chosen because a whitespace follows each colon character `':'`) and also removes the whitespaces. ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Got it,  we are spliting all the words on whitespace and then choosing only with `:`

Comment: yes this is one way of doing it. many other possibilities. whichever best makes sense to you and accomplishes your goal :)

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, capture the none space `(\S)` characters before a ie parenthesis are used to capture. \S means opposite of space. `:`. In this case, you can simply do:

```
import re 

re.findall(r'(\S+):',data_description)
 ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num']
```

if you need to take the `\n` into consideration, maybe because there might be some in the data which are not column names yet succeeded by a colon then:

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|\n)(\S+):',data_description)
 ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first remove all `\n` that are imported with the string, and then apply some `split()`and `filter()` methods, like this:

```
data_description = data_description.replace("\n", "")
columns = [i.split(":")[0] for i in  list(filter(None, data_description.split(".")))]
```

Now you get the name of each column:

```
columns
['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num']
```

There is not a general rule. For each case you have to think how to remove leading and trailing whitespace and try use methods like `split` in a way you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one-liner.

```
print([every_line.split(':')[0] for every_line in data_description.split('\n')])
```